# Creating an iOS Simulator Build of CocoaPods project

Tags: ios, facebook, build, ios-simulator, cocoapods

I need to create a simulator build in order to submit my app to facebook team for further review of my open graph.

They have a instruction to create that here [facebook instruction](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/)

But I use cocoapods and I can not make this build. everytime it gives me error.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator{version} -workspace [projectName].xcworkspace -scheme [projectName]
```

Follow the steps [Click here](https://king107.blogspot.in/p/how-to-create-simulator-build-and-run.html)

Comment: One thing to note. This tends to run the build as a 'Run' not an 'Archive'. So if you set Debug on 'Run' but not 'Archive' (which is pretty common), be sure to swap 'Run' over to a release state for this if you intend to give them a release type build.

Comment: For you non terminal experts, your xcworkspace file may be 2 directories up. Just use ../../<projectName>.xcworkspace instead.

Comment: I applied this. It says Build secceeded! But I can not find the build folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please check the terminal log and find the Build Path. copy that path.
now open "Finder" window,
Finder menu -> Go -> Go to Folder.
Paste the build path.

Comment: Thank for this! But is it the exactly same steps for an iPad app only ? Because Facebook rejects all the time my build. It's an iPad app (not iPhone) and when I use ios-sim launch, the app start in the iPhone and doesn't works. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Lapinou: If facebook reject your build continuously then create one demo iPhone build with facebook integration. And upload demo build project for facebook approval process. Right now, its work for me.

Comment: you anyone suggest my app name is " ABC XYZ.workspace ", how to write in terminal to run the above compand

Answer (score 12):

**Here is the another easy method to create .zip file**

- Step 1: open finder and press command⌘ + shift⇧ + g
- Step 2: paste "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
- Step 3: select your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh some thing like this
  folder
- Step 4: your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh >>Build>>Products>>Debug-iphonesimulator
- Step 5: You will see 2 files one is your_app_name.app(icon like rounder and 1 cross line ) and 2nd file
  is your_app_name.app.dSYM
- Step 6: To create .zip file right click on
  your_app_name.app and select "Compress your_app_name". It will
  generate .zip file and submit it to facebook.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved me millions of times

Comment: The command line code!! you can get it from above answer which is posted by #Tibidabo

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but the DerivedData folder is empty even after I have run my app. If it is relevant, I am using Expo

Answer (score 6):

I'm in the same boat and have been struggling with this!

I managed to get my build working by adding the following to the command line args:

```
-workspace [Name.xcworkspace] -Scheme [NameOfScheme]
```

I also had to edit the scheme and add the Pods target explicitly as it was failing the build with `Library not found for -lPods`.

Comment: I did not need to manually add the pods target.  Also, in case you're wondering what your scheme name is, it is in the top left between the run/stop buttons and the target selector and is probably the name of your project.

Answer (score 6):

Having the same issue, I had both errors fixed @bean his error by adding 'i386' to the "valid architectures" in build settings. (for my app target, pod target and every pod separately)

My full build command is:

```
xcodebuild -workspace [projectName].xcworkspace -scheme [schemeName] -arch i386 -sdk=iphonesimulator7.1
```

I can complete the build but I get tons warnings:

```
warning: no rule to process file '[any .m file]' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture i386
```

I have no idea how to fix this, an .app file is created just not on the location the facebook tutorial says it should be (its in "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.." instead of "{projectDir}/build/...")

Now 2 questions remain for me:

1.) How can I test or this .app file works (double-clicking it tells me the file is damaged.)

2.) (Why) Can I not just build the app from within Xcode using the simulator and just submit the .app file that Xcode created?

Comment: If you add these arguments it will build to build/Debug-iphonesimulator:  OBJROOT=$(PWD)/build SYMROOT=$(PWD)/build.  To run use ios-sim: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim

Answer (score 5):

Facebook updated its guidelines how to make a simulator built ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started))

> 1. Run your app in your Xcode iPhone 5 simulator. This automatically creates a simulator build in Xcode's DerivedData cache.
> 2. Run: **ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip**
>      This automatically zips the simulator build.
> 3. You can verify the simulator build by using the ios-sim utility Command-line App Launcher for Simulator.
> 4. Submit YourApp.zip.

Comment: where do I have to run the second step ? thanks for your help

Comment: @user5370095 same place as described in the link in the accepted answer (your project directory). Also, `path/to/YourApp.zip` can just be `~/Desktop/YourApp.zip`

Answer (score 2):

it's simple as going to **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/XXXX.app** copy you **XXXX.app** from there and copy to desktop ..right click and select compress.. you will a zip file for your app.Submit it to fB

Answer (score 1):

Developers who has failed with @Pradip Vanparia's Solution like me this will work:

```
xcodebuild -workspace {project name}.xcworkspace -scheme {project name}  -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator9.3
```

And I found `iphonesimulator9.3` by following command:

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

Answer (score 0):

The just "Copy/Past" way :

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` MyApp.zip
```