# Creating an iOS Simulator Build (for Facebook review)

Tags: ios, facebook, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I'm following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build), but when I run this command:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

I got this error:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>   Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/andG.app/andG normal i386
>   (1 failure)

So please help me solve!

Comment: This error might mean whatever..

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problem with dependency targets...This post helped me, maybe it's your case too [ios simulator build using workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482823/creating-an-ios-simulator-build-of-cocoapod-project) You should provide some more arguments in your build command like workspace and scheme

```
-workspace [Name.xcworkspace] -scheme [NameOfScheme]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -workspace [name].xcworkspace -scheme [targetName or ProjectName]
```

also the path of the build maybe different to what Facebook mentioned in there documentation you can find the build under `{Derived data directory}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/{projectname}.app`

Answer (score 0):

1. The present working directory should be the project main directory
2. Try xcodebuild -arch armv7s -sdk iphonesimulator7.1

Comment: The build for an iphone simulator should be in i386 architecture.