# How can create simulator build of application which uses camera?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, terminal, ios-simulator, ios10

I have developed one application in which camera is used. App uses camera for video recording and also my app is totally based on camera. Now I have to submit app for `Facebook` review as I have used `FacebookLoginSDK`.

`Facebook App review` requires simulator build, but all you know how can we access camera in simulator ?

So how can I show my app to `Facebook` ?

I have referred below guidelines :

1. http://king107.blogspot.in/p/how-to-create-simulator-build-and-run.html
2. [Creating an iOS Simulator Build of Cocoapod project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482823/creating-an-ios-simulator-build-of-cocoapod-project)

My build is created successfully, but the problem is cannot access camera.

If anyone have alternate solution, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's no way you can test camera function of your app if you're using a simulator. 
The best solution is to get an iOS device, borrow from someone you know that owns iOS devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html

Comment: I know very well that I cannot use camera in simulator. But my question is I want to create simulator build for `Facebook` review. They can't test my app. So I am looking for alternative solution of submitting build.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstood.
So the problem is that they cannot access the camera?
Have you include the permission in info.plist?